# FTP Creating a new user in AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, ftp, bitnami

I have installed an instance in Amazon AWS with Bitnami Wordpress.

I need to create a user to be accessed via ftp, however, without having to use amazon's sftp.

Can someone help me create a ftp user and direct it to /home/bitnami/apps/wordpress.

Comment: why not sftp ? with sftp you can use the same user you're using for ssh with the same key and you will have access to your directory for up/down-load file. If you want to create a new user just use `adduser` (and give a password) and make sure this user has access to your directory

Answer (score 1):

There is already a FTP server in the Bitnami AMI and you can connect via SFTP to your server as described in the guide below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#how-to-upload-files-to-the-server-with-sftp

You can find more information about the Bitnami WP AMI at the link below:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/